# Errors setting up a Monero pool

Tags: monerod, hard-fork

I'm having issues running the daemon on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.
I have download the blockchain.raw then imported it, then I've gone to run ./monerod 
and I'm getting this:

```
2018-07-28 09:45:39.690     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:279 Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.1.0-release)
2018-07-28 09:45:39.690     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:55    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2018-07-28 09:45:39.690     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:60    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2018-07-28 09:45:39.691     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63 Initializing p2p server...
2018-07-28 09:45:44.096     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:68 P2p server initialized OK
2018-07-28 09:45:44.096     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:58 Initializing core rpc server...
2018-07-28 09:45:44.097     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:70 Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
2018-07-28 09:45:44.097     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63 Core rpc server initialized OK on port: 18081
2018-07-28 09:45:44.097     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:73    Initializing core...
2018-07-28 09:45:44.097     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:323 Loading blockchain from folder /root/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2018-07-28 09:45:44.972     7f8f1dbbd740    WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:72   Error attempting to retrieve a hard fork version at height 1601485 from the db: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
2018-07-28 09:45:44.983     7f8f1dbbd740    FATAL   daemon  src/daemon/daemon.cpp:150   Uncaught exception! Error attempting to retrieve a hard fork version at height 1601485 from the db: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
2018-07-28 09:45:44.983     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:90 Deinitializing rpc server...
2018-07-28 09:45:44.983     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:90 Deinitializing p2p...
2018-07-28 09:45:44.983     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:89    Deinitializing core...
2018-07-28 09:45:45.008     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:77    Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2018-07-28 09:45:45.008     7f8f1dbbd740    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:81    Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
```

Please can someone let me know as there's not much info out there about this error.

Kind regards
M1

Answer (score 1):

> Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.1.0-release)

You're running an outdated version of monerod. Download and run the latest version (currently v0.12.3).

Comment: ok i deleted the .blockchain dir then started the monerod again with updated version and it is now syncing hopefully it works now :) thanks for the input